# wpf: bind border width with image width

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm adding a functionality to my program which views image thumbnails to listview.

What i want is bind the width of border to my image but i can't make it work

here is my code

```
        <Border x:Name="imgbrdr" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
     <ListView Name="Thumbnails" SelectionChanged="Thumbnails_SelectionChanged" >
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Height="{Binding ElementName=imgbrdr}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
               </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
</Border>
```

Comment: While the question asks about the width, your code tries to bind the height. Which one is it actually?

Comment: Your requirement is ... strange. Can't you just let the image fill available space with `Stretch="Uniform"` (and probably `StretchDirection="DownOnly"`)?

Comment: @grek40 See my answer. Uniform is the default Stretch.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, the listview scrollbar should do the trick. The question is a typical XY, where an answer to the question is not a solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add the property path of the `Border`.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source}" Height="{Binding ElementName=imgbrdr, Path=ActualHeight}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
```

Comment: its working now. but how do i lessen the size of the border when i pass it to the image.

example the size of border is w= 200 but i want to pass to the image is 180 only. i tried ActualWidth - 20 but it doesn't work

Comment: You cant add calculation in Xaml,you might need a Converter there.

Comment: @WPFUser how do i solve my problem? thank you, can you give me some hints

Comment: you need to write class inherited from IValueConverter, and need to add your calculations on Convert method and finally need to refer that conevrter in your xaml..similar requirement resolved here  http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-3-WPF__DataBinding_to_Calculated_Values--The_IValueConverter_interface.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that Binding at all.

To make the images the same width as the ListView, you only need to disable horizontal scrolling. You can then also set a Margin on the Image controls. With a ListView width of e.g. 200 and a Margin of 10, the images would be 180 wide.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note also that you could as well use a ListBox, which is the base class of ListView.